# Displaying classes as .cs instead of child of a class in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have been working on an assignment for my class and everything is going well, however when looking at other programs they are structured in visual studio such as:

```
FirstClass.cs
SecondClass.cs
```

My program has a structre such as

```
Program.cs
    Program
    Menu
    etc..
```

However, its not methods of a class, they are all classes that I have created but they do not display such as my teacher would like it.

Here is a picture of how my teacher wants it:

[image]

Here is a picture of how mine look:

[image]

As you can see, I would like my classes to all appear as .cs and not as a child of Program.cs. Everything is working fine, I just want to understand whats wrong with the way I have created and how to solve it?

Comment: How many .cs files do you have?

Comment: The rule (guideline) is to put every class in its own file.

Answer (score 1):

Put each class in its own file. Solution explorer shows that you have a single file called Program.cs that contains a bunch of classes. Program, Menu, WholeNumbersForAdd, etc. Put each of these in their own files called Menu.cs, WholeNumbersForAdd.cs, etc.

That's why this works: the classes you defined are okay, you've just put them all in a single file, which is okay, but not really convenient, and not how your teacher wants it.

Answer (score 1):

You've put everything in 1 file (program.cs). Your teacher is simply asking you to split it out to separate classes, each in their own file.

This is good practice, they're teaching you right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put different classes written in Program.cs to another cs files
you can use ctrl + shift + A then a menu will open as below.

Select the class and change the name to whatever you want to do then press add button.

This will work for you.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Do not use the following structure:

[image]

Instead use the following context menu's:
[image]

And next:

[image]